# How to center a GNOME pop-up notification?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pynotify

To display a GNOME pop-up notification at (200,400) on the screen (using Python):

```
import pynotify

n = pynotify.Notification("This is my title", "This is my description")
n.set_hint('x', 200)
n.set_hint('y', 400)
n.show()
```

I'm a gtk noob.  How can I make this Notification show up centered on the screen, or at the bottom-center of the screen?

Perhaps my question should be "what Python snippet gets me the Linux screen dimensions?", and I'll plug those into set_hint() as appropriate.

Comment: Does it really matter if the notification is in the center of screen? Why can't you let the window manager decide where it should go?

Comment: i am working on a continuous testing setup for python, where every time i modify a file, the unit tests for my project are run, and a popup shows success or failure.  it's pretty useless over in the bottom-right corner of the screen, because it pulls my eyes away from my work -- i might as well leave a console open.  i want the notification to subconsciously inform me, like Growl on Mac would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using GNOME, here's the GTK way of getting the screen resolution

```
import gtk.gdk
import pynotify

n = pynotify.Notification("This is my title", "This is my description")
n.set_hint('x', gtk.gdk.screen_width()/2.)
n.set_hint('y', gtk.gdk.screen_height()/2.)
n.show()
```

Comment: Works great, although I think the periods after the "2"s are typos.

While I'm at it, any idea how to get the width of the notification itself, so I can subtract half of that off of the center of the screen?

Comment: The periods after the "2"s are to make them floating point numbers - to avoid doing integer division which could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but this works:

```
from Tkinter import *
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
width, height = r.winfo_screenwidth(), r.winfo_screenheight()
```

Another option is:

```
from commands import getstatusoutput
status, output = getstatusoutput("xwininfo -root")
width = re.compile(r"Width: (\d+)").findall(output)[0]
height = re.compile(r"Height: (\d+)").findall(output)[0]
```

Answer (score -4):

on windows,

```
      from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
      width = GetSystemMetrics (0)
      height = GetSystemMetrics (1)
      print "Screen resolution = %dx%d" % (width, height)
```

I cant seem to find the linux version for it tho.

Comment: GNOME doesn't run on Windows. This answer is completely useless.

Comment: Not for those that might want to do the same under windows ;)

Comment: I would like to not get viruses in Windows do you know how to do that in python?